# No bootable devices ... after lost partitions

Tags: partitioning, grub2, hard-drive, boot-repair

This is an issue I've been working on for days.

After attempting to access and external HDD from a Dell Lattitude E6420, the machine will not boot.  My guess is that I inadvertently applied a change to the onboard HDD.  I have looked at the drive thru GPARTED, and done a rescue with TESTDISK, but no luck.

I then ran BOOT REPAIR DISK, all from the ubuntu 20 live USB.  It created a link but did not fix the boot issue.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p8zPMpQkmf/

My hope is that the data is still intact, and therefore do not want to do a full install.  The old backup was on the failed external drive.

This is a computer my parents use and things may not go well if I have lost all their data!

Just to add, I'm half Linux capable but don't know more than I know.

I'm sure there is more info that can be added.  I can run any command on command line you might need.

Thanks

Comment: I am not an expert in interpreting boot-repair output but it looks like there is no bootable system on that computer (i.e. no operating system installed).

Comment: You are showing only one ext4 partition and Boot-Repair did not show any of the normal boot files or fstab which it should have found. Drive is now gpt, but you have not bios_grub for a correct install of grub into a gpt drive for BIOS boot. Or you need an ESP for UEFI type boot with the UEFI version of grub.

Comment: @w calvert : as your `sda` drive has a GPT layout, did you check that your BIOS operates on "UEFI mode" ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I agree that there is no bootable system, no boot files etc.  There is also clearly a grub issue?

Comment: Regarding the UEFI mode question, I can only boot thru Ubuntu Live usb.  I can look at the boot options but I know it is not set to boot legacy mode.